# Shiny app automate Hive query and email result after done

Tags: python, r, bash, hive, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app which accepts input file from user, do a few hive queries against that input file and then send an email with the query result to the user with the output as attachment.

Quesiton1: The shiny server doesn't belong to the hadoop cluster and I am wondering will `RHIVE` package work in this case?

Question2: Regardless of `RHIVE` will be used or not, after I send the query to HIVE, how can I be notified when the query finishes? Usually, I manually do those kind of work in Cloudera Manager and come back after 1 or 2 hours of running queries.

I am kind of automating this process using R/Python/bash. If the connection to HIVE has to be done in Python/bash, I will try to call the Python and bash script in my shiny app to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that may help.  It waits for an event to occur, and then sends an email and gives a little GTK+ popup.  You might want to use the script to notify when your process finishes, but if you'd rather not, you could study it to learn how to send e-mail messages in Python.

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/notify-when-up2.html